# Error when testing ionic app on IOS device

Tags: ionic4

**I have this error when i test ionic app on IOS device**

i have adding the signing but i have the same error
i test this app on browser and emulator is working with xcode but on device ios not working this is the error

> Showing Recent Issues
>   Signing for "MyApp" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.

**please someone can help me ?**

Answer (score 0):

first try to clean and rebuild the project again. But if it works in the browser and emulator, but not on a device. This is a symptom that you havent paid and have a valid anual license of xcode